# Creating a date projector in c#

Tags: c#

So I am trying to create a report form that will automatically calculate expected dates for key events in a process. Currently the program creates the projections based on the date the process is started. I can not figure out how to make it take into account if the projections are different from the actual date the event takes place.

I can see why my code functions the way it does, just not sure how to go about changing it.

This code pulls certain things from the database but the projections are clearly calculated locally and do not get sent to the DB.

```
DateTime recDate = DateTime.Now;
DateTime resaltDate = DateTime.Now;
DateTime springDate = DateTime.Now;
DateTime summerDate = DateTime.Now;
DateTime releaseDate = DateTime.Now;
int size = 0;

MySqlConnection conDatabase = new MySqlConnection(conString);
MySqlCommand cmdDatabase = new MySqlCommand(query, conDatabase);

try
{
    conDatabase.Open();
    MySqlDataReader myReader = cmdDatabase.ExecuteReader(); ;
    while (myReader.Read())
    {
        size = myReader.GetInt32("size");
        recDate = myReader.GetDateTime("recDate");
    }
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
}

springDate = dateTimePResalt.Value;
summerDate = dateTimePSpring.Value;
releaseDate = dateTimePSummer.Value;   

if (size == 0)
{
    dateTimePResalt.Value = recDate.AddDays(6);
    dateTimePSpring.Value = springDate.AddDays(44);
    dateTimePSummer.Value = summerDate.AddDays(58);
    dateTimePRelease.Value = releaseDate.AddDays(70);
}
else if (size == 1)
{
    dateTimePResalt.Value = recDate.AddDays(6);
    dateTimePSpring.Value = springDate.AddDays(47);
    dateTimePSummer.Value = summerDate.AddDays(61);
    dateTimePRelease.Value = releaseDate.AddDays(73);
}
```

Comment: "and do not get sent to the DB" - yes, you'd need to write separate code to update the database. Changes to variables in your .NET code won't make any changes to the database directly. It's not quite clear what you're asking for at the moment.

Comment: Please don't ever code `catch (Exception ex) { ... }` - it's lazy and dangerous.

Comment: *"but the projections are clearly calculated locally and do not get sent to the DB"* - Where are you trying to perform these operations?  When you debug, what specific operation produces an unexpected result?  What were the relevant runtime values used?  What result did you expect?  Why?  It's not clear to me exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Ok, there are 2 fields. An actual date and a projected date. How would I cause the later projections to update based on if the actual date of the earlier steps in the process.